# netsh advfirewall open TCP ports 80 and 443 for outgoing traffic

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-firewall, netsh

I need to do the following with netsh advfirewall commands:

Open TCP ports 80 and 443 for outgoing traffic to dc.services.visualstudio.com and f5.services.visualstudio.com.

How can I do this?

Comment: Downvoting me instead of giving answers, real nice you guys :(

Comment: [How to use the "netsh advfirewall firewall" to control Windows Firewall behavior](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709)

Comment: `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule ?`

Comment: I know I should use add rule, I just don't know what the rule should be

Comment: especially since the examples I found just used an ip adress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Get IP Address for services.visualstudio.com

```
C:\test>nslookup services.visualstudio.com
Server:  dns.tb.iss.as9143.net
Address:  212.54.40.25

Name:    services.visualstudio.com
```

---

#### Open the ports

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open port 80" protocol=TCP localport=80 action=allow dir=OUT remoteip=212.54.40.25
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open port 443" protocol=TCP localport=443 action=allow dir=OUT remoteip=212.54.40.25
```

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - Configure Network Interfaces, Windows Firewall, Routing & remote access.
- [How to use "netsh advfirewall firewall" to control Windows Firewall behavior](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/947709)